# getpwnam() crashes program when invalid user is entered

Tags: c, linux, return, system-calls

In **getuserinfo()** if the line **struct passwd *theUser = getpwnam(username);** is attempted with a username that doesn't exist the program just closes with an error of -1. It never gets to the error handling portion of the function. It doesn't return to main and I'm not sure why.

It should return NULL and print out the error message and let the rest of the program attempt to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <errno.h>


//awk 'BEGIN { FS=":"; print "User\t\tUID\n--------------------"; } { print $1,"\t\t",$3;} END { print "--------------------\nAll Users and UIDs Printed!" }' /etc/passwd
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
#/bin/bash \n\
awk 'BEGIN { FS=\":\"; print \"User\t\tUID\n--------------------\"; } { print $1,\"\t\t\",$3;} END { print \"--------------------\nAll Users and UIDs Printed!\" }' /etc/passwd \n\
    "



struct passwd *getuserinfo(char *username)
{
    //Set errno to 0 so we can use it
    errno = 0;

    //create a variable to store the user info in
    struct passwd *theUser = getpwnam(username);

    //error check getpwnam()
    if(theUser == NULL)
    {
        printf("getpwnam() ERROR, errno = %d", errno);
        return NULL;
    }

    return theUser;
}

struct group *getgroupinfo(long int groupid)
{
    //Set errno to 0 so we can use it
    errno = 0;

    //create a variable to store the group info in
    struct group *theGroup = getgrgid(groupid);

    //error check getgrgid()
    if(theGroup == NULL)
    {
        printf("getgrgid() ERROR, errno = %d", errno);
        return NULL;
    }

    return theGroup;
}

void displayusers()
{
    system(SHELLSCRIPT);
}

/*
 *
 *  4. A main function which will
 * Call getuserinfo passing a hard-coded username, and using the return object, display the user id. (10 points)
 * Call getgroupinfo passing the return object from getuserinfo, and using the return object, display the user’s group name. (10 points)
 * Call displayusers. (10 points)
 *
 * My main function does those things but I don't pass objects since the function prototypes you gave us
 * don't accept that input, they want ints and strings
 */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Take in the username we want to look up
    char username[50];
    printf("Enter username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);


    //look up the user and get their info
    struct passwd *theUser = getuserinfo(username);
    //use the user's gid and look up its info
    struct group *theGroup = getgroupinfo(theUser->pw_gid);

    printf("User: %s\nUser ID: %d\nGroup Name: %s\n\n\n", theUser->pw_name, theUser->pw_uid, theGroup->gr_name);

    displayusers();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the code have setuid privilege, or are you running this as root?

Comment: I'm just running this in the Eclipse for C/C++ console. I would guess that the code then runs as my user who is an admin, but not using sudo.

Comment: You are assuming the code will pass, `struct passwd *theUser = getuserinfo(username);` and follow on merrily to the next line to obtain the group id of that user, did you not check for `NULL` there before calling the function `getgroupinfo`?

Comment: Add a `fflush()` after the `printf()` in `getuserinfo` and you will see the error message. (Note: errno will be 0, indicating the user was not found.)

Answer (score 0):

### The error checking should look like this:

```
struct passwd *getuserinfo(char *username)
{


//define errno so we can use it
errno = 0;
//create a variable to store the user info in
struct passwd *theUser = getpwnam(username);

//error check getpwnam()
if(errno != 0)
{
    perror("ERROR: getpwnam() FAIL");
}
//check if we got user data/if the user existed
else if(theUser == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: User does not exist!\n");
    return NULL;
}

    return theUser;
}
```

fprintf using stderr needed to be used to make sure the error message was always displayed. It was getting lost in the printf buffer, keithmo's suggestion of using fflush(NULL) figured that out.

errno is used to check if the call succeeded. We then make sure the theUser != NULL because the call is successful even if there is a missing user. If it's NULL we print an error message to the user so they're aware.

We also error check before we call getgroupinfo in the main function now as per t0mm13b

```
//look up the user and get their info
    struct passwd *theUser = getuserinfo(username);
    //use the user's gid and look up its info
    struct group *theGroup;
    if(theUser != NULL)
    {
        //get the user's group id
        theGroup = getgroupinfo(theUser->pw_gid);
        //print the user and group info
        printf("User: %s\nUser ID: %d\nGroup Name: %s\n\n\n", theUser->pw_name, theUser->pw_uid, theGroup->gr_name);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: No group info, missing user!\n");
    }


    displayusers();
```

Comment: I suspect that using stdout instead of stderr wasn't the issue - I suspect that it was actually due to not originally including a newline, which would delay flushing. You just happened to also include a newline in your new version.